# About using .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

hope you are dong fine.

I have have a subfolder in my public_html folder.
In the subfolder, I have a .htaccess file with the following code:

```
# Disable indexing:
Options All -Indexes
# Ignore every file:
IndexIgnore *
# Prevent access to any file:
<FilesMatch "^.*$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Now when I browse to the subfolder, for example, *www.mysite.com/subfolder/myfile.php*, I shown my site's index.html page!
Can this really be happening?!

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to show a generic "Access not allowed" page?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have _another_ `.htaccess` file in the document root directory of your site? This `.htaccess` does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: You are right lanzz. Just found another .htacess file in my public_html folder (which was created by Drupal) which is showing the index.html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved.
The problem was caused by another .htacess file in my public_html folder (which was created by Drupal) which is showing the index.html page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to throw a Forbidden error for all access in a directory, you can add this to the htaccess in that directory (this require mod_rewrite to be enabled, wich most of the time is) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please tell me what I need to do to show a generic "Access not allowed" page?

You simply need this inside the htaccess file in your directory that you want to deny access to:

```
Deny from All
```

that's it. No need to use other modules or anything special. This denies any access to this directory.